# Create DB to store company listings

Tags: sql, mysqli

So I am looking at creating a very small app for the town I live in, I would like to offer people the ability to log into a website and create a business listing that would have things like (name, address, phone, opening hrs, logo -image).

I have limited knowledge in sql and creating Databases but am able to with abit of reading and time.. However I would like to know the best approach for storing images.

I am planning on just uploading the image to the webspace and then having a URL link stored in the DB... But not really sure if this is the best option?

So my question first of all, is this the best way to go about it? secondly how could I achieve this?

Comment: For something so broad, just google "SQL store Images"... Should list several discussions of best practice, and code project examples of how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got everything right.

Yes, go for the plain table in the database, contains all the required fields.

Upon inserting another company data, get the autoincremented id, extract logo's filename extension and move uploaded file into a file called `"$id.$ext"` and you're all set.

How to achieve it - just try some online manuals. 
There are plenty on working with database, while handling files is better to learn from the man page http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php